# sed issue replacing a negative value

Tags: sed

I have a file where some entries look like:

```
EMIG_BAD_ID                     = syscall.Errno( -0x12f)
```

I want to use sed to replace that negative number to make it positive,

```
EMIG_BAD_ID                     = syscall.Errno( 0x12f)
```

I've tried some ideas from web searches but not succeded.
E.g. this one exits with an error:

```
egrep EMIG_* _error.grep | \
   sed -e 's/syscall.Errno(\1)/syscall.Errno(-\1)/g' _error.grep
sed: -e expression #1, char 40: Invalid back reference
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The question is a little more complicated, sorry for not giving the whole story.  cat _error.out | grep -f _error.grep | sed 's/=\(.*\)/= syscall.Errno(\1)/' After that line I need to find lines with a negative number and convert them to positive ones. Fortunately all lines having negative numbers start with EMIG_ Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the format is exactly like you posted, you can use this fairly easy replacement:

```
sed 's/syscall.Errno( -/syscall.Errno( /g' _error.grep
```

To make the space between `(` and `-` optional:

```
sed 's/syscall.Errno( \?-/syscall.Errno( /g' _error.grep
```

To answer your question / if you insist on using back references (and optional space), here's how to use back references:

```
sed 's/syscall.Errno( \?-\(.*\))/syscall.Errno(\1)/g' _error.grep
```

Some additional notes:

- You don't need grep - if `EMIG_BAD_ID` is on the same line it's very easy to include that in the sed matching pattern.
- You pipe from egrep to sed *and* let sed read from a file. That doesn't make sense. You should prefer reading files directly with sed; but if you need grep, just read from stdin (without the file argument). Specify `-i` with sed to perform an in-place edit.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E '/^EMIG/s/-([0-9]+)/\1/' input_file
EMIG_BAD_ID                     = syscall.Errno( 0x12f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. Unfortunately I don't have a working answer yet.
Code below: (part of a bigger file)

cat _error.out

```
E2BIG                           = 0x40000007
EMIG_ARRAY_TOO_LARGE            = -0x133
```

cat test.sh

```
cat _error.out | sed 's/=\(.*\)/= syscall.Errno(\1)/'
```

Result:

```
E2BIG                           = syscall.Errno( 0x40000007)
EMIG_ARRAY_TOO_LARGE            = syscall.Errno( -0x133)
```

The problem is to use bash/grep/sed to make the negative number positive.

Thanks!